# Outlook Email Categorisation

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I am using Outlook Interop to read and Categorize the e-mail when they arrive.

This is the event I use :

```
 Outlook.Items items;
 items = inbox.
 items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
```

And inside Switch statement later on I have code like this :

```
case "Subject":
    mail.Categories = "Category";
    mail.UnRead = false; break;
default:
    mail.Categories = "Attention needed";
    mail.UnRead = false;
    mail.Save();
    break;
```

The issue is that sometimes the Inbox receives 5 e-mails per second and only categorizes the first and the last e-mail, while the other just get the UnRead = false without the Category.

Are there any other events that I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemAdd` event is not fired when multiple items are received (typicaly, more than sixteen). That is a known issued in OOM.

Instead, you need to subscribe to the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem` , `MeetingItem` , or `SharingItem` . The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the `EntryIDCollection contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)